# How do I reload new settings of LXTerminal without closing it?

Tags: configuration, lxterminal

I wrote a Bash script that changes the font and adjusts its color in
LXTerminal,

```
sed -i -E 's/^(fontname=.{3,})10/\122/;s/^(fgcolor=rgb)\(.*\)/\1\(255,255,255\)/' ~/.config/lxterminal/lxterminal.conf
```

In order to see the changes I need to close all my tabs and open LXTerminal again. How might I script reloading the new settings so that I can see them in already opened tabs
without needing to close them? It has to be non-interactive, i.e done by the script and not by me clicking the **OK** or **Save** button in GUI.